# Regex or way to replace multiple space with single space

Tags: java, regex, spring

Could you please let me know is there any way to replace multiple space with single space in java or spring? Any stringUtils function for same?

like

1.

```
test     test
test test
```

2.

```
test  test
test test
```

3.

```
test                    test
test test
```

Comment: The problem with string utils is they won't replace variable lengths of characters, so you have to default to a single char. But doing this ends up taking a huge amout of time. Better to do this with a regex.

Answer (score 28):

To replace multiple spaces

```
output = input.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
```

Or replace multiple whitespace characters (including space, tab, new line, etc.)

```
output = input.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a variation of @p.s.w.g - it ignores newlines, but still get tabs and such.

`output = input.replaceAll("[^\\S\\r\\n]+", " ");`